How to encrypt plain text in such a way that encryption will matched with our saved record encryption?
The problem is that let say I have a model called Propose and i use Active Record Encryption to encrypt some attributes as shown in below code:
class Propose < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :email, :phone_number, :name, :first_name, :last_name, deterministic: true
  scope :search_filter, -> (params) do
    #search_keyword = Proposer.encrypt_email(params[:keyword])
    if params[:keyword].present?
      where(search_filter_query, "%#{params[:keyword]}%", "%#{params[:keyword]}%", "%#{params[:keyword]}%", "%#{params[:keyword]}%", "%#{params[:keyword]}%").distinct
    else
      all
    end
  end

  def self.search_filter_query
    <<-SQL
    proposes.email like ?                or
    proposes.first_name like ?           or
    proposes.last_name like ?            or
    proposes.phone_number like ?  
    SQL
  end
end

I  tried something like for testing I passed in params the encrypted key that is saved in database. lets  say my Propose.last give me a data in which email encrypted key is saved something like mentioned below
"{\"p\":\"z6nB0w==\",\"h\":{\"iv\":\"mjYo3/B7Va2h328F\",\"at\":\"Q+Jy3OevXCDc+S2t71Og7w==\"}}" 

so it give me the record but my main question is that how we can encrypt the search keyword if someone enter email like vishwani1@gmail.com and I have record for this email in my db but it is encrypted i want to encrypt this email same as it is saved
so after encrypted this email i want same like  mentioned below:
"{\"p\":\"z6nB0w==\",\"h\":{\"iv\":\"mjYo3/B7Va2h328F\",\"at\":\"Q+Jy3OevXCDc+S2t71Og7w==\"}}"

I tried some Active Record Encryption Module Class methods mentioned below:
ActiveRecord::Encryption.encryptor.encrypt('vishwani1@gmail.com')

but this genrate different key now not the same this time it give me
"{\"p\":\"vNQnGUg/DqyCLCxTiho8w2ukZ7tughGA\",\"h\":{\"iv\":\"KxI7O8GQ2M8s/EGI\",\"at\":\"YWOQyLZLcBr4TWffMCqMUA==\"}}"

then I tried with determinstic
ActiveRecord::Encryption.encryptor.encrypt('ravi.kumar@riskcovry.com', cipher_options: {:deterministic => true})

this generate a diff key
"{\"p\":\"h7UfLswp9dQWAKLHl5c5EgesVu273CVo\",\"h\":{\"iv\":\"9AQAiIJM4zA/tVJ8\",\"at\":\"4URjKQq/FYGKH7X/uDpEvA==\"}}"

but if i hit above command again i get this above key but I want the key that is create at the time  we saved that data.
So is it possible to encrypt like that?

Asking the same question over and over doesn't change the fact that what you want is not possible.

"I want the key that is create at the time we saved that data" – so you encrypted the existing data in your database using the non-deterministic approach? If so, you can't re-create the output, that's the whole point. You could convert your data by decrypting each record and then re-encrypting it with deterministic: true.

As a sidenote you are passing 5 parameters to a query that only uses 4 and you could shorten your scope to where(search_filter_query, *["%#{params[:keyword]}%"] * 5), also distinct does not seem necessary since there are no joined associations. None of this changes the fact that this is not a functional possibility they are merely notes on the code presented.

Ruby on Rails supports deterministic encryption to searching for a value in the database.
That only works for exact matches, because – with deterministic encryption – Rails will encrypt the search term and query the database for the exact encrypted term.
To be able to do a LIKE query of any kind, the database would need to have access to the unencrypted text to compare parts of the content. But the database cannot decrypt the value because it doesn't know the required secrets. And Rails cannot build a LIKE query with an encrypted substring. Because when you encrypt a substring, then the encrypted substring will not be context in the full string's encrypted version.
What is supported by Rails' deterministic encryption, is searching by exact matches. And that works out of the box as a normal ActiveRecord query, for example, like this:
# in the model
scope search_filter, ->(query) do 
  where(email: query)
    .or(where(first_name: query))
    .or(where(last_name: query))
    .or(where(phone_number: query)) if query
end

# in the controller
Propose.search_filter(params[:keyword])


Thanks spickermann for the answer, I already tried this solution but it only works for exact match

That is the whole point of my answer, what you want to do, is impossible. Not because of Rails, but because of how encryption works in general. You cannot search encrypted strings by their substrings. If that was possible, then the encryption would be very weak and easy to break (like a Caesar cipher for example).

Would Elastic Search can be better solution for it?

No, because it is not possible because that is how secure encryption works. It has nothing to do with Rails or the database being used. When you want to be able to search by substrings, then you cannot use a strong encryption at the same time. There are workarounds (like blind index), but those have limitations too.
